# Meaning of operator ~> in Scala ?

Tags: scala, operators

I'm trying to understand if this operator (`~>`) means any in Scala or if it's domain specific?

I'm trying to understand the Scala code here. 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/example-1-dataset.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~>` has no special meaning in scala. In this case, it is just a method defined by ScalaNLP Breeze (See http://www.scalanlp.org/api/#breeze.text.tokenize.Tokenizer)

Comment: Note that `~>` is also a method in [Scala's parser combinators library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser).

Comment: Indeed. However, the code snippet linked by the OP does not use parser combinators, but does use scalaNLP.

Comment: ~> is also used as an operator in Unfiltered (e.g. http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Response+Functions.html)